# ERROR: Too many arguments: quarto-ext/grouped-tabsets

Tags: r, ubuntu, quarto

I'm trying to install a quarto extension on ubuntu but getting the following error:

```
$ quarto install extension quarto-ext/grouped-tabsets
ERROR: Too many arguments: quarto-ext/grouped-tabsets
```

Interestingly I can't find the `install` argument:

```
$ quarto -h
  Usage:   quarto 
  Version: 0.9.522
                  
  Description:
    Quarto CLI
  Options:
    -h, --help     - Show this help.                            
    -V, --version  - Show the version number for this program.  
  Commands:
    render          [input] [args...]   - Render input file(s) to various document types.   
    preview         [file] [args...]    - Render and preview a document or website project. 
    serve           [input]             - Serve a Shiny interactive document.               
    create-project  [dir]               - Create a project for rendering multiple documents 
    convert         <input>             - Convert documents to alternate representations.   
    pandoc          [args...]           - Run the version of Pandoc embedded within Quarto. 
    run             [script] [args...]  - Run a TypeScript, R, Python, or Lua script.       
    tools           <command> [tool]    - Installation and update of ancillary tools.       
    check           [target]            - Verify correct functioning of Quarto installation.
    help            [command]           - Show this help or the help of a sub-command.
```

but I can't find any other alternative to install extensions via the quarto commandline tool. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Upgrade Quarto. You need at least v1.0.15 to install extensions. https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/

Comment: thanks this worked. happy to accept as an answer.

Comment: great - I have added a bit more info and posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/) indicates that You need Quarto v1.0.15 or greater to install extensions.

You can find the latest stable version [here](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/).

Alternatively, to install the [dev version](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli) on Ubuntu/Mac, you should remove your current installation and then run:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli
cd quarto-cli
./configure.sh
```

On Windows this would be:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli
cd quarto-cli
./configure.cmd
```

If you have already installed the dev version in the past you can update it simply by navigating to the parent folder and running:

```bash
cd quarto-cli
git pull
```